# How can I create a text file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-files, creation, filesystemobject

I am trying to create a text file using JavaScript. I have tried the following code, but this didn’t work. What is the solution?

```
var fso, file;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
file = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\Mytest\test.txt");
file.Close();
```

Comment: ActiveX stuff only works in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it using *ActiveXObject* as it works only in Internet Explorer... Have a look on *[File System APIs of HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)* which may help you.

Comment: Always welcome....!!!

Comment: How to make it work on other browsers like chrome, FF and safari ?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) only works in Internet Explorer. And you need define a function and call this.

```
<script>
    function wtf() {
        set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        set s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\test.txt", True);
        s.writeline("HI");
        s.writeline("Bye");
        s.writeline("-----------------------------");
        s.Close();
    }
</script>

<body onload="wtf()">
```

Comment: jajaja wtf = write to file jeejeje

Comment: How to make it work on other browsers like chrome, FF and safari ?

Comment: In FF, Chrome, Others. you can use HTML5 (its supported) check this: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/